# dotCover: Generate HTML report with UTF-8 encoding

Tags: encoding, utf-8, teamcity, dotcover

I'm using TeamCity 10.0.4 and activated dotCover for my tests. It works as it should but the resulting HTML files from dotCover is encoded in ANSI and not UTF-8. This causes a problem since TeamCity it self is encoded in UTF-8 and the cover report is loaded in an iframe and thus instead of swedish characters åäö I get the black square with a questionmark.

Is there any way to change how dotCover encodes the report files?